# Open file upload dialog on click of an icon

Tags: html

I want to be able to open the file upload dialog when the user clicks on an icon without showing a file input element.

I have the following code with the icons and the file input elements:

```
<div class="col-md-5 col-sm-5">
    <div class="tools">
        <ul class="publishing-tools list-inline">
            <!--<li><a href="#"><i class="ion-compose"></i></a></li>-->
            <li><a href="#"><i class="ion-images">
                <input type="file" name="image" accept="image/gif,image/jpeg,image/jpg,image/png" multiple="" data-original-title="upload photos">
            </i></a></li>
            <li><a href="#"><i class="ion-ios-videocam">
                <input type="file" name="video" accept="video/mp4,video/x-m4v" multiple="" data-original-title="upload video" >
            </i></a></li>
            <!-- <li><a href="#"><i class="ion-map"></i></a></li>-->
        </ul>
        <button class="btn btn-primary pull-right" name="btn_publish">Publish</button>
    </div>
</div>
```

That code displays like this:

[image]

How can I hide the file input element and activate the file dialog corresponding to each icon when the icon is clicked?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Just add an label tag and wrap input tag inside label and hide input and give it a id which will be used on label for attribute.

```
<label for="file">
  <i class="ion-images"></i>
  <input type="file" id="file" style="display: none" name="image" accept="image/gif,image/jpeg,image/jpg,image/png" multiple="" data-original-title="upload photos">
</label>
```

Comment: kindly tell me one think more,? i am facing a problem to upload video

Comment: You can remove the `for="..."` if the input element is inside the label.

Comment: If you are looking for a solution in react, use htmlFor property in label and make sure the htmlFor and input id have the same name.